# Pending Transactions after crash - recovery?

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool

I have a question, is it possible to recover somehow pending transactions if the geth node crash ?

Right now I assume that there is now recovery mechanism. In this case if transactions enter the txPool with pending status and the node crashes we will not be able to recover this transaction ? Am I right ? Maybe it is possible in clustered nodes environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for recovery; if the transaction is in the transaction pool, the node synchronizes (relays) it to its peers that further relay the transaction to the rest of the network which will confirm it (mine it and broadcast the result to the block chain).

If the node crashes and the transaction is not relayed, then peers have no idea that the transaction was made and as such it can be redone (once the **geth** node recovers) without any loss of balance.